# switching between devices in processing 3 changes how things look

Tags: processing, screen-resolution

I'm using processing 3 to make my game and I have a major issue where the game looks completely different when running on a different device. The two devices have different resolutions which might be the problem. How do I fix this? Here is a picture of how it looks when I run it on my device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNDGY.png
Here is a picture of how it looks when I run it on my friend's device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ80S.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two screens have a different resolution and the buttons sometimes overlap, then I'm guessing the following are both true:

- Buttons are constant width
- Buttons positions are based on fraction of screen width -- not an absolute position

If you want to display the buttons at smaller resolutions and maintain gaps between them, you'll have to also **scale the button widths** (and height) based on the current resolution.